# Not able to get the value from Object array using angular

Tags: angular

```
this.testervice.getTestList(this.testData).subscribe(       
    (data: TestModels.ListTestModel) => {
    let testListData = data as any; 
        this.testListData = testListData;
        this.testListDataValue = this.testListData.map(function (testList) { return testList.testName }); 
    })         
}
```

"testListData" is contains the given values

```
{"test":null,"title":null,"testList":[{"testName":"Test.COM","testId":1},{"testName":"Test1.COM","testId":2}],"count":2}
```

I want to get the testName values(Test.COM & Test1.COM) in variable this.testListDataValue, please help.

Comment: I think you just need to change it to `this.testListData.testList.map`, otherwise your not calling map on your array

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpgx2g

Comment: Did you look at the solution Provided by me? Did not it work?

Answer (score 0):

You're not accessing the actual test list and you are not sharing scope when you use "function" inside of the mapping function.

Try this:

```
this.testervice.getTestList(this.testData)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {

            this.testListData = data;
            this.testListDataValues = data.testList
                .map(test =>  test.testName );

        })  

}
```

Comment: I'm getting error : [ts] Property 'testList' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: What exactly is in the data variable? console log it

Comment: ERROR in src/test.component.ts(194,59): error TS2339: Property 'testList' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: ok, change (data: TestModels.ListTestModel) to just (data: any) for now then see what that prints

Comment: Model:
  export interface ListTestModel {
    test?: any;
    title?: any;
    testList: TestList[];
    count: number;
  }  
  export interface TestList {
    testName: string;
    testId: number;
  }
  
 .ts 
     testListData: any[]; 
  testListDataValues: any[];  
  
  this.testervice.getTestList(this.testData)
    .subscribe((data: TestModels.ListTestModel) => {
 
            this.testListData = data;
            this.testListDataValues = data.testList
                .map(test =>  test.testName );

        })  
  }

Comment: Still I'm getting this error:  I'm getting compile [ts] Property 'testList' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: so console.log(data) is printing an interface? That doesn't make sense. What does the getTestList method from your testService look like? Can you add that to your question.

Comment: its not printing  the interface in console, just added for reference. Also getting below in console:

Comment: {test: null, title: null, testList: Array(2), count: 2}
testList:Array(2)
0:{"testName":"Test.COM","testId":1}
1:{"testName":"Test1.COM","testId":2}
length:2